# The use of "please" in instructions

Tags: politeness, imperative-sentences

I'm translating instructions for my company's employees on how to enter data into a database. Most of the instructions are phrased as statements rather than imperatives (e.g. "In this field XX should be entered"),but there are also a few imperatives, notably about different things that should be noted. A direct translation of these instances would be "Note that XX". Now I'm wondering whether or not I should add *please* in these instances – that is, would it be considered strange/impolite not to have *please* here?

Comment: Using "please" is a stylistic choice, one that is driven by whatever style guide you're using, even if it's just an in-house style guide. If you don't have one, you need one. Inconsistency makes instructions hard to read.

Comment: Instructions do not normally include *please*, because *please* is part of a polite request, and instructions are just a list of steps to follow.  It would sound very strange if an instruction manual said, "1.  Please put ground coffee in the basket.  2.  Please put cold water in the container.  3.  Please press the power button" etc. etc.

Comment: @stangdon Haha – you're right :) I guess I got tricked by the fact that most of the instructions I'm translating aren't in the imperative; if they had been, I'd probably have realised that I shouldn't use *please*. Thanks for pointing this out to me!

Comment: You should also consider wording all the instructions consistently. For example, make all of them imperative, even if that isn't how things would be done in your native language. "Enter XX in this field" is easier to read (for English speakers) than "In this field XX should be entered".

Comment: @ThePhoton Oh, I totally agree! Thing is, it's just as inconsistent and weird in my own language, so I'm not sure I can just change it... I can (and will) bring it up for discussion though :)